# Why Z-index is always interpret as above everything else in Google Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, z-index

An element has the following CSS property:

```
#mask {
  display: none;
  background: transparent; 
  position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; 
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

and another element which is supposed to appear **on top** of it:

```
.login-popup {
  display:none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

It turns out just fine on FireFox. On Chrome, this #mask is being projected above everything else. Chrome is Version 24.0.1312.70. What could be wrong?

Note: Both the elements are manipulated using JavaScript. The JavaScript does not interfere with the Z-index property in any way.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbesr/8/

Comment: They have both `display: none`, so they are not visible at all.

Comment: ? you are using `display: none;` so how will that even mask?

Comment: Actually it's supposed to be a transparent mask. It's supposed to prevent one from clicking any URLs beneath it.

And both are created at runtime using JavaScript. So that it stays hidden initially and can be made to fade-in.

Comment: @SamikSengupta `display: none;` so anyways that will fail

Comment: @some nah, now it makes sense, he said JS

Comment: Check my edit. It's called on using JavaScript at runtime. I don't need it to exist otherwise.

Comment: your mask has less z-index than your login popup just saying

Comment: The login popup is supposed to be above the mask.

Comment: can you post a fiddle please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zbesr/8/

This is the jsfiddle. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because #mask has opacity less than 1.. New stacking orders apply when you have opacity. Interesting article that describes exactly why this happens:
http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/